# XCUITEST - pressForDuration broken by Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got some UI tests in an iOS app which used to work, but now fail.  I just installed the GM version of Xcode 8.  Here's a typical code fragment.

```
    let inoutbuttonSwitch = app.switches["inOutButton"]
    let offTapPoint = inoutbuttonSwitch.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.25, 0.5))
    let onTapPoint = inoutbuttonSwitch.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.75, 0.5))
    offTapPoint.pressForDuration(0.1)
```

The UISwitch in question is initially off.  I get a coordinate in the left half of the switch, and another in the right half.

Before, this would successfully turn the switch off.  But now the pressForDuration had no effect.

Any ideas of how to get around this?

Comment: I've investigated this a bit further. In playing around with recording a test, Changing a switch now gets one of the two buttons within the switch to turn it on or off. I also notice that there appear to be some new control specific apis for apple controls like adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition:) for changing sliders.  BUT it looks like using coordinateWIthNormalizedOffset to either tap or drag within a control no longer works.  I have some custom controls which I can no longer interact with in UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem, but only in landscape orientation. I use the following extension as a work around.

```
// fix coordinate for landscape bug in Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)
extension XCUICoordinate {

    func fix() -> XCUICoordinate {
        let window = XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0)
        let baseCoordinate = window.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0))
        switch XCUIDevice.shared().orientation  {
        case .landscapeRight:
            return baseCoordinate.withOffset(CGVector(dx: self.screenPoint.y, dy: window.frame.width - self.screenPoint.x))
        case .landscapeLeft:
            return baseCoordinate.withOffset(CGVector(dx: window.frame.height - self.screenPoint.y, dy: self.screenPoint.x))
        default:
            return self
        }
    }
}
```